# How to possible number type input field in wordpress cmb2?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to possible number type input field in wordpress cmb2 ? I want number type input field and set default value.

```
        $cmb->add_field( array(
        'name'    => __( 'Number Title', 'myprefix' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'field description (optional)', 'myprefix' ),
        'id'      => 'number-id',
        'type'    => '',
        'default' => '30',
    ) );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name' => 'Standard Number Field',
    'description' => 'Number Field',
    'id'   => $prefix.'test_number',
    'type' => 'text',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type' => 'number',
    ),
    ) );
```